# saving gtk window position

Tags: c, linux, gtk

I'm trying to save the gtk window position(absolute) to restore it wehn I open the applicaiton again

here's my code so far:

```
gint x,y;
  gtk_window_get_position(main_window,&x,&y);
  printf("current position is:\nx: %i\ny:%i\n",x,y);
```

this code runs when the application exits, I always get:
current position is:
x: 0
y:0

What am I doing wrong.

Comment: [The documentation for `gtk_window_get_position()` answers this question in detail.](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-get-position)

Answer (score 4):

`gtk_window_get_position` usually does a **best guess** but you cannot rely on it because

> the X Window System does not specify a way to obtain the geometry of
>   the decorations placed on a window by the window manager.

*(from [gtk_window_get_position reference](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-get-position))*

To see the function in action, try something like below:

```c
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argv, char* argc[])
{
    GtkWidget *window, *button;
    gint x, y;

    gtk_init(&argv, &argc);
    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Test Window");
    button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Close");

    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(button), "clicked", 
            G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), (gpointer)NULL);
    gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(window), 10);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), button);
    gtk_window_get_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), &x, &y);

    printf("current position is:\nx: %i\ny:%i\n", x, y);
    gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), 
            GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER_ALWAYS);
    gtk_window_get_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), &x, &y);

    printf("new position is:\nx: %i\ny:%i\n", x, y);
    gtk_widget_show_all(window); 


    gtk_main();
}
```

**Edit**

If you wish the window to appear at a specific location, you could try something like:

```c
 gtk_window_move(GTK_WINDOW(window), 420, 180);
```

However the above function should be placed after

```c
gtk_widget_show_all(window);
```

because

> most window managers ignore requests for initial window positions
>   (instead using a user-defined placement algorithm) and honor requests
>   after the window has already been shown.

*(from [gtk_window_move reference](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-move))*

Comment: when I used the ste function I got:
0,0(before the set) 
583,284 (after the set function)
620,370  (when I close)

thing is I always get 620,370 no matter where my window is

Comment: `GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER_ALWAYS` means `always center the window`. You could use `gtk_window_move (GTK_WINDOW(window), x, y)` to move the window to a more specific location. ie give your own integer values for x & y. See my edit @AdelAhmed.

Comment: move works like a charm, if I move the window though, I cannot get its coordinates again :(

Comment: You're already moving the window using the coordinates, nop? ;)

Comment: yeah, I have implemented a small function that can read the mouse coordinate, so that can be managed for now. I would like to automate it to save it's position on close and move on optn

Comment: on a redhat server, both set and move commands DO NOT change the window's position :(

Answer (score 0):

I've just implemented this feature using [`pygobject`](https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/); it's not C but it could still be useful to have a look at it.

You can find the code [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/tallero/indoor-farming-simulator).

I've used GNOME Builder's default template for a python GNOME application, so it should be super-easy to replicate if you set your project with it.